# Not sure how to go about solving this proof

Tags: functions

Let $A$ be a set with $|A| = n$. Suppose $x \not\in A$ and $y \in A$.

Prove that $|A-\{y\}| = n-1$.

Comment: Hint: If $y$ is in $A$, then the number of elements in $A$ equals 1 more than the number of elements in $A-{y}$.

Comment: What is x supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Since $|A| = n$ you can index it's elements i.e we can write $A = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Here $y \in A$ implies $y = x_j$ for some $j = 1,...,n$ i.e $A - \{y\} = A - \{x_j\} = \{x_1,...,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},...,x_n\}$. You can now rename your elements: $x_1= x_1',...,x_{j-1} = x_{j-1}', x_{j+1} = x_{j}',...,x_n = x_{n-1}' \Rightarrow A = \{x_1',...,x_{n-1}'\}$ and now the cardinality is clearly $n-1$.